# Получить id последнего сообщение отправленного ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Например у нас есть переписка:

```
bot: Привет!
user: Привет!
user: Как дела?
*n-ое количество сообщений от user
```

Как получить id последнего сообщения, которое было отправлено ботом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поместить сообщение в переменную. Что то типа такого:

```
msg = bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='текст')
```

Затем отправить его в чат

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=msg.message_id, text='тут текст')
```

тогда id сообщения бота будет `msg.message_id`